# Equality holds in triangle inequality iff both numbers are positive, both are negative or one is zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

How do we show that equality holds in the triangle inequality $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$ iff both numbers are positive, both are negative or one is zero? I already showed that equality holds when one of the three conditions happens.

Comment: You can simplify your hypothesis to "both non-negative or both non-positive".

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944302/when-does-the-equality-hold-in-the-triangle-inequality

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $|a+b|=a+b=|a|+|b|$. If they are negative, then $|a+b|=-a-b=|a|+|b|$. Suppose one of them is $0$. Without loss of generality suppose $a=0$. Then $|a+b|=|b|=|a|+|b|$.

If none of the three situations occurs, then between $a$ and $b$ one is positive and one negative. Without loss of generality, suppose $a$ is positive. Suppose $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$. If $a+b\geq 0$, then $a+b=a-b$ so that $b=0$, a contradiction. If $a+b<0$, then $-a-b=a-b$ so that $a=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: This is exactly the end of the proof I started writing. Do I have to show what happens when a is positive and b is negative and also a is negative and b is positive or one of the situations is enough?

Comment: can I write the following after showing when the inequality is equal:
In order to complete the proof we will show an equality isn't a result when one of the parameters A or B is positive and the other is negative (which of them is not important because A*B is a product):
$$ab-|ab|<=0$$

Comment: I clicked Enter by mistake without finishing the proof:

can I write the following after showing when the inequality is equal:
In order to complete the proof we will show an equality isn't a result when one of the parameters A or B is positive and the other is negative (which of them is not important because A*B is a product):
$$ab-|ab|<=0$$
$$ab+ab<=0$$ (We get rid of the absolute value by taking minus out of it)
$$2ab<=0$$
$$ab<=0$$ (We divide both sides of the inequality by 2)
$$ab<0$$ Because the product of A positive and B negative is negative.

Comment: After showing that when A,B are both positive or negative or one of them equals to zero the inequality equals, I show the only one left scenario which is one one of them is positive and the other is negative. This way I cover all of the options and I complete the IFF proof, right?

Answer (score 11):

Because $|a+b|$ and $|a|+|b|$ are nonnegative, the inequality $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$ is equivalent to
$$(|a+b|)^2 \leq (|a|+|b|)^2,$$
which becomes after simplification
$$ab \leq |ab|.$$
The equality clearly then holds iff $ab$ is nonnegative.

Answer (score 3):

If we have
$$|a + b| = |a| + |b|$$

Then we have two cases. First
$$a + b = |a| + |b| \implies a-|a| =|b|-b$$
Both sides in the above are either simultaneously zero (in which $a = |a|$ and $b = |b|$) or simultaneously not zero, in which ($a \neq |a|$ and $b \neq |b|$). The first case is simultaneously positive and the second implies $|a| = |b| = 0$.

Similarly for the other case
$$ -a - b = |a| + |b| \implies -|a|-a = b+|b|$$
in which the same analysis applies.

Answer (score 0):

If we have $|a+b | = | a | + | b|$, squaring both sides we obtain
$$|a+b|^2 = (|a| + |b|)^2$$

$$\iff a^2+2ab+b^2 = |a|^2 + 2|a||b| +|b|^2 = a^2 + 2|a||b| + b^2.$$

Finally, $$ab = |a||b| \ge 0 .$$

So that, $|a+b| = |a| + |b|$ iff $ab \ge 0$.