# Under what conditions is $|x+y|=|x|+|y|$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

What instance that this equation would be true?

$|x+y|=|x|+|y|$
Given that $x$, $y$ are elements of real numbers.

Comment: It is true whenever $xy\ge 0$.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are of the same parity.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944302/when-does-the-equality-hold-in-the-triangle-inequality or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226569/equality-holds-in-triangle-inequality-iff-both-numbers-are-positive-both-are-ne (You can probably find a few more related posts.)

Comment: I guess you are asking in connection with [your previous questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352226/help-me-solve-this-problem).

Answer (score 10):

$|x+y|=|x|+|y| \iff |x+y|^2 = (|x|+|y|)^2 \iff x^2+2xy+y^2=x^2+2|xy|+y^2 \iff xy=|xy| \iff xy \geq 0$.

Comment: A proof of the converse is missing. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

The statement will be true when any of the following conditions is satisfied:

(i) $x=0$ or $y=0$ or both are zero,

(ii) $x=y$,

(iii) $x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$,

(iv) $x\le0$ and $y\le0$.

Comment: What about $x=-1$, $y=-2$?

Comment: I have extended the conditions.