# Find the precise conditions under which we have $\|x+y\| = \|x\|+\|y\|$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ consider (the norm infinity) $\|x\|=\max|x(i)|$ where $1\leq i\leq n$.

Find the precise conditions under which we have $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$.

Thank you for your helping. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\operatorname{arg max}(|x|)=\operatorname{arg max}(|y|)$ is a necessary condition to $\max|x_i+y_i|=\max|x_i|+\max|y_i|$. Here, $\operatorname{arg max}(|x|)= k$ such that $\max(|x|)= |x_k|$

Now,$|x_k+y_k|=|x_k|+|y_k|$ . Then either $x_k$ and $y_k$ have the same sign or at least one of then is 0. In the last case, $x=[0,\dots,0]$ or $y=[0,\dots,0]$

Comment: This might be useful  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944302/when-does-the-equality-hold-in-the-triangle-inequality

Comment: i'm not good at english language but i try to understand in your advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you sum $n$ pairs of numbers, the maximum of the $n$ results is the sum of the maximums if you had to add precisely these two maximums, and if they had the same sign.