# What are the solutions of $|x+y|=|x|+|y|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

So I am having a problem in solving this type of equation. 
The problem I am dealing with is...

$$\left|(2x-1) + \frac{3x-1}x\right| = \left|2x-1\right| + \left|\frac{3x-1}x\right|$$

Please help me with this problem. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Real numbers? Or complex? Probably reals, I'm guessing, but it does make a difference...

Comment: See [Equality holds in triangle inequality iff both numbers are positive, both are negative or one is zero](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226569/equality-holds-in-triangle-inequality-iff-both-numbers-are-positive-both-are-ne) (and maybe some other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/226569)).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: If considered over the reals, $|a+b| = |a| + |b|$ holds if and only if $a$ and $b$ are of same sign, or at least one of $a, b$ is $0$.

For you question, determine the intervals over which $2x-1$ is positive/zero/negative, and the intervals over which $(3x-1)/x$ is positive/zero/negative, and then take suitable unions/intersections. (Care must be taken at then endpoint $x = 0$, since $x$ appears in denominators.)

Comment: Thanks. I got your point :)

Answer (score 4):

Another approach, assuming $x$ and $y$ are real:
$$\begin{aligned}
|x+y| = |x| + |y|
&\iff |x+y|^2 = (|x|+|y|)^2 \\
&\iff (x+y)^2 = |x|^2 + 2|x||y| + |y|^2 \\
&\iff x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = x^2 + 2|x||y| + y^2 \\
&\iff 2xy = 2|x||y| \\
&\iff xy = |x||y| \\
&\iff xy = |xy| \\
&\iff xy \geq 0 \\
\end{aligned}$$
In your case, the original problem is therefore equivalent to
$$(2x-1)\left(\frac{3x-1}{x}\right) \geq 0$$
which should be straightforward to solve.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Then just wavy curve application is required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A brute force approach is to drop one set of abs bars and replace the equation by two alternatives, one with "$+$" and one with "$-$" before the group that carried the bars.

The alternatives are logically "ORed", so each solution to each alternative is a solution to the original.

This can then be continued to double the number of equations again and again.